# Convert pandas series of json objects to DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a pandas series of json objects from a slice of a DataFrame to a new DataFrame with the keys as columns. I've tried all similar solutions, but nothing seems to work. It either returns the same series, or generates errors. Some of the lines have different keys, they're not all the same, and the number of elements varies. There's a limited amount of variation, so each key can have it's own column. Is there a way to convert this type of series into a DataFrame?

```
1       {'length': '27 mm', 'style': 'Short', 'width': '9 mm'}
2       {'length': '51 mm', 'style': 'Long', 'width': '9 mm'}
5       {'length': '29 mm', 'style': 'Medium', 'width': '9 mm','id': '16684'}
6       {'width': '7 mm', 'length': '29 mm', 'style': 'Medium','mfg': '45-163'}
8       {'width': '8 mm', 'length': '33 mm', 'style': 'Medium'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would suggest

1. convert every json to dict
2. convert every dict to DataFrame
3. concat all dataframes, preserving indices

Data is in `series` in this example. Also It replaces `'` with `"`:

```
import json
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(json.loads(s), index=[ind]) for ind, s in series.str.replace('\'', '"').items()], sort=False)
```

```
    length  style   width   id      mfg
1   27 mm   Short   9 mm    NaN     NaN
2   51 mm   Long    9 mm    NaN     NaN
5   29 mm   Medium  9 mm    16684   NaN
6   29 mm   Medium  7 mm    NaN     45-163
8   33 mm   Medium  8 mm    NaN     NaN
```

Comment: It gives an error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`. Also I want to keep the index to merge back later.

Comment: @Matts it means, that json in your string must have double quotes instead of single quotes. You can do it with, say, `df[0].str.replace('\'', '"')`

Comment: @Matts adjusted it according to your comments

Comment: getting an error `JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 99 (char 98)`

Comment: @Matts double-check your input, make sure that these are strings and not, say, dicts (otherwise  you don't need `json.loads` at all). I've tried with your data and it worked just fine. Maybe `strip` every string would help, don't know. Once again - it works with the series that you posted (given that these jsons are plain strings).

Comment: Any value that contains a single quote is already double quoted, so can't replace these single quotes. e.g. "Size 1/2\'\'" results in "Size 1/2""" after the replace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to get it working after using some different regex to replace. There were also double quotes in the single quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have valid JSONs (e. g., double quotes, valid syntax etc., see discussion in [Viacheslav Zhukov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59909959/8777313)) in your series, you can also use

```py
import json
pd.DataFrame(
    my_json_series.apply(json.loads).to_list()
    , index=my_json_series.index  # optional if you want to keep the index
)
```

avoiding the for loop/list comprehension and being **much** faster.
These steps are rather

1. convert each JSON to dict
2. concat all dicts in a list/make the series a list
3. make a `DataFrame` from the list

Also, I don't get a proper `MultiIndex` with the proposed for loop.

```
In [110]: %%timeit
     ...: my_out_df1 = pd.DataFrame(
     ...:     my_json_series.apply(json.loads).to_list()
     ...:     , index=my_json_series.index  # optional if you want to keep the index
     ...: )
362 ms ± 5.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [111]: %%timeit
     ...: my_out_df_2 = pd.concat(
     ...:     [pd.DataFrame(json.loads(s), index=[ind])
     ...:      for ind, s in my_json_series.items()],
     ...:     sort=False
     ...: )
14.9 s ± 310 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I have to add that I tested with a completely different series than yours, mine had 4 elements in each json and about 10,000 elements in the series.

EDIT 2: To solve the problem with single quotes you could also try `eval(my_single_quote_json)` instead of `json.loads`.  This even works if your JSON has varying quotes as it would read your string as Python code.  If your JSONs contain `null`s, you first need to define a variable `null = 'some value or None'`.  Of course, using `eval` is never optimal, but it may help.